# ¿Posible traducción para "drop zone" en español?

Tags: traducción, expresiones, vocabulario-técnico, españa, deportes

El otro día tuve con un golfista una interesante discusión. Viendo un campeonato de golf en la tele vi que uno de los participantes había mandado la pelota fuera del campo, tras unas casetas. Así que fue, agarró la pelota y se la llevo a un recuadro pintado en el suelo con el siguiente cartel: "Drop zone".

[image: Drop zone]

<sup>Zona de *dropaje*</sup>

Pregunté qué era eso, y la respuesta fue que era la zona donde se *dropa* la pelota cuando te sales del campo, para continuar con el hoyo a partir de ahí. Ahí fue cuando comenzó la discusión. Pregunté si no había un término adaptado, y me dijo que no, que todo el mundo decía "dropar" y "zona de dropaje". En un principio me pareció un atentado al idioma, pero mi interlocutor contraatacó argumentando que una persona que usa *setear*, *resetear*, e incluso *banear* no puede ponerse así (*touché*).

[image: Cómo dropar]

<sup>Para continuar con el juego, se deja caer una pelota en la zona.</sup>

Luego ya pensé que tanto en la literatura española como en las propias aplicaciones que hacen uso de estos términos tan comunes en la informática se los intenta traducir, y así tenemos *establecer*, *restablecer*, *expulsar* y demás. Sin embargo, en el ámbito del golf de momento no parece que haya intención de usar otros términos aparte de los adaptados del inglés, de hecho me avisan de que si intento usar otras palabras que no sean *dropaje* o *dropar* me van a mirar raro.

Sin embargo, otros términos sí que se han adaptado, como decir que se va a usar el "hierro 4" para golpear la pelota, y otros se han dejado en inglés al no existir una palabra previa, como *[green](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JWKZNc1)*, que incluso ya está presente en el diccionario. El problema que le veo a "drop zone" es la mala traducción del verbo *to drop*, "dejar caer". Si fuésemos a traducir la expresión, me salen cosas como "zona de caída" (?), "zona para soltar la pelota" (o "dejar caer"), expresiones que suenan forzadas o son demasiado largas.

Por tanto, ¿cuál podría ser una traducción de "drop zone" que suene natural en español?

<sub>NOTA: Respuestas aceptadas en español de España o en español neutro.</sub>

Comment: Un inculto del golf aquí presente :) ¿Es decir que el "drop zone" es el lugar donde se sitúa la pelota cuando se la recupera para el juego después de que haya salido del campo? ¿Como cuando en el futbolín sale fuera y la tiras dentro otra vez?

Comment: Yo también soy bastante inculto en el golf, pero se entiende que es así como tú dices.

Comment: Veo que incluso la guía de la Federación Española de Golf está plagada de anglicismos: http://www.rfegolf.es/ArtculosDocumento/REGLAS/RFEG_Reglas_de_Golf_2012-2015.pdf

Comment: Qué feo “zona de dropaje”. En Argentina se usa “zona de dropeo”, mucho mejor `;)`. ¿Esta pregunta no es demasiado subjetiva?

Comment: He cambiado la etiqueta de "jerga" por "vocabulario técnico", porque entiendo que más que un coloquialismo buscamos un término técnico dentro de este deporte.

Comment: por si interesa: [glosario del golf](http://www.golfsitges.com/vocabulario)

Comment: @Diego sin problema, reconozco que me lié un poco con las etiquetas, la que propones queda mucho mejor. :)

Comment: @Diego de hecho [se decidió](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/a/2575/1674) que _jerga_ sea sinónima de _vocabulario-técnico_, para distinguirla de _coloquialismos_. Voy haciendo el deslinde poco a poco (5-6 al día, para no molestar demasiado), si os animáis a colaborar, yo encantado :)

Comment: @fedorqui, es que hace tiempo que no paso por meta. Si me explicas cómo se está haciendo el deslinde (que supongo que será editando preguntas para cambiar el tag) yo arrimo el hombro y me ocupo de las que pueda.

Comment: @Diego genial, yo encantado. Lo que hago se resume en [esta revisión](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/posts/16323/revisions): quito [jerga], añado lo que corresponda y pongo un comentario explicativo. Cuando termine el proceso marcaré [jerga] como sinónima de [vocabulario-técnico]. Y si tienes aún más tiempo, echa una ojeada a la pregunta genérica [¡Ordenemos las etiquetas!](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2495/1674) a ver si se te ocurren también sugerencias o pasos a seguir. Carlos ya dio unos cuantos buenos. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bueno, siendo esta pregunta hipotética (ya que evidentemente tanto en España con *zona de dropaje* como en la Argentina con *zona de dropeo* están ya bien situadas dos traducciones muy... buf...)

Pero pensando en la función de esta zona, que es la que se usa cuando no se puede encontrar la pelota por salir del campo, ya hay una palabra muy nativa para expresar dicho concepto:

> **[saque](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XHSreto)**
>   **1.** *m.* Acción de sacar. || **2.** **saque** que se realiza para iniciar o reanudar el juego de pelota y otros deportes || **3.** Raya o sitio desde el cual se saca la pelota. […]
>   ***saque* de esquina.**  **1.** *m.* En el fútbol, **saque** que se hace desde una esquina del campo por un jugador del bando atacante por haber salido el balón del campo de juego cruzando una de las líneas de meta, tras haber sido tocado en último por un jugador del bando defensor.

Fijaos que literalmente la definición hace referencia al acto que se realiza en la zona (por lo que se podría decir *zona de saque*) y también a la zona sí misma (por lo que se podría decir, sencillamente, *el saque* como traducción de *drop zone*).

Yo, en este caso, prefiriendo formas menos parecidas al inglés, diría que aprovechemos de la posibilidad de usar una sola palabra y que al *drop zone* lo denominamos como **saque** a secas.  Así que si la pelota se encuentra muy fuera del campo, podríamos decir algo como «Vaya, será imposible encontrar esa pelota.  Tomaré el pénalti y empezar en el saque» o «Está perdida esa pelota.  Voy a poner otro en el saque».

Comment: Vaya hombre! Nosotros aquí con "zona de dropeo" y "zona de trastumbo" y tienes que llegar tú con algo razonable como "zona de saque"... Desde luego! ;-) +1 Creo que aunque hay una zona de saque (inicial) en golf no se la denomina como tal (es **salida o marca**), pero igual podría llevar a confusión (posiblemente solo para no iniciados).

Comment: @Diego a la zona de salida inicial se la denomina el _tee_.

Answer (score 5):

Entiendo que esta pregunta busca una respuesta específica para el golf. En aviación también se usa el término "[drop zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drop_zone)" que se traduce (paradójicamente) como "[zona de salto](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=drop%20zone)".

De la explicación entendemos que es una zona donde dejas caer la pelota para recontinuar el juego. No se *lanza*, no se *coloca* ni *sitúa*, simplemente la dejas caer (y rodar) y desde ahí sigues con el juego. Eso elimina muchos sinónimos de `soltar` como ["posar"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TmMR2xL) ya que no colocamos la pelota suavemente.

Usando el DIRAE me he encontrado con [trastumbar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aWADaZc) <sup>1</sup>

> De tras- y tumbar.
>
> 1. tr. Dejar caer o echar a rodar algo.

que creo que describe bien la acción que se realiza con la pelota (aunque no se la echa a rodar en plan *petanca*). Convirtiendo el verbo en un nombre, podemos denominar a la `drop zone` como "zona de trastumbación" o "zona de trastumbo".

---

<sup>1</sup> Si es la primera vez que oyes "trastumbar" en tu vida, ya somos dos :-)

Comment: @guifa, quita quita, lo añado, que queda bonito.